# Asynchronous get user products from Mongo

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm trying to create a method that can get the products of an user. Already have one that can returns the product matching provided id.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProduct(string productId)
        {
            try
            {
                var product = await _productService.GetProductAsync(productId);
                if (product != null)
                    return Ok(product);
                _logger.LogWarning($"Could not find product : {productId}");
                return NotFound(new ApiError(ErrorCode.NotFound, "Could not find product"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error retrieving product : {productId}");
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ApiError(ErrorCode.ServerError, "Internal server error", "Please contact developer"));
            }
        }
```

How I need to do in order to get user products? I tried a lot but no results.

Comment: Welcome. I suggest taking the time to read and understand the content explained at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and various other [help center topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) you really should have been directed to on signing up a new account before posting your first question. All you have given us is a block of existing code which is actually by your own explanation completely unrelated to the question you are asking. Consider revising after reading that material.

Comment: To be specific.  There is no description of structure or the desired result included, nor are we sitting at your desk and thus we do not have access to what your data looks like or what you expect unless you show us. If you want a question answered, then you need to give as much information is as necessary to solve it. The current "question" has none of this.